# C++, not obvious usage of typename keyword

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following class declaration:

```
    template <typename T, size_t N>
    class CircularBuffer {
        public:
        using iterator = typename std::array<T, N>::iterator;
        ...
    private:
        std::array<T, N> m_elements;
        ...
    };
```

Without "typename" keyword in "using "iterator = typename std::array::iterator;" compiler issues an error:

```
   error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::iterator’ because ‘std::array<_Tp, _Nm>’ is a dependent scope.
```

But the statement
       "using iterator = std::array::iterator;" 
compiles.

As I understand "using" keyword is used only (except "using namespace ...") for creating type aliases, then why is there the need for "typename" at all in the above examples? 
Thank you!

Comment: using alias = ...; can only create type aliases; So the right-hand side can only be type, not value.

Comment: It is like writing: int Integer = int another_integer;